# Mongoose Error: 'Cast to ObjectId failed' Message in the 'Book' Model

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose

When trying to send a DELETE request to my backend application to delete a book from the 'Book' model, I'm getting a Mongoose error message that reads: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value 'undefined' (type string) at path '_id' for model 'Book'."

It appears that Mongoose couldn't interpret the "_id" field as an ObjectId type because its value is "undefined," and its type is "string."

The application sends the DELETE request from a frontend application, and it seems that the "id" value is being passed incorrectly during the request. I'd like to know what might be causing this error and how to fix it in either the frontend or backend code.

**booksRoute.jsx**

```
import express from 'express';
import { Book } from '../models/bookModel.js';

const router = express.Router();

// Route for Save a new Book
router.post('/', async (request, response) => {
  try {
    if (
      !request.body.title ||
      !request.body.author ||
      !request.body.publishYear
    ) {
      return response.status(400).send({
        message: 'Send all required fields: title, author, publishYear',
      });
    }
    const newBook = {
      title: request.body.title,
      author: request.body.author,
      publishYear: request.body.publishYear,
    };

    const book = await Book.create(newBook);

    return response.status(201).send(book);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    response.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
  }
});

// Route for Get All Books from database
router.get('/', async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const books = await Book.find({});

    return response.status(200).json({
      count: books.length,
      data: books,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    response.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
  }
});

// Route for Get One Book from database by id
router.get('/:id', async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const {id} = request.params;

    const book = await Book.findById(id);

    return response.status(200).json(book);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    response.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
  }
});

// Route for Update a Book
router.put('/:id', async (request, response) => {
  try {
    if (
      !request.body.title ||
      !request.body.author ||
      !request.body.publishYear
    ) {
      return response.status(400).send({
        message: 'Send all required fields: title, author, publishYear',
      });
    }

    const {id} = request.params;

    const result = await Book.findByIdAndUpdate(id, request.body);

    if (!result) {
      return response.status(404).json({ message: 'Book not found' });
    }

    return response.status(200).send({ message: 'Book updated successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    response.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
  }
});

// Route for Delete a book
router.delete('/:id', async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const {id} = request.params;

    const result = await Book.findByIdAndDelete(id);

    if (!result) {
      return response.status(404).json({ message: 'Book not found' });
    }

    return response.status(200).send({ message: 'Book deleted successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    response.status(500).send({ message: error.message });
  }
});

export default router;
```

**DeleteBook.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import BackButton from '../components/BackButton';
import Spinner from '../components/Spinner';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';

const DeleteBook = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const handleDeleteBook = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:5555/books/${id}`)
      .then(() => {
        setLoading(false);
        enqueueSnackbar('Book Deleted successfully', { variant: 'success' });
        navigate('/');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        enqueueSnackbar('Error', { variant: 'error' });
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  
  return (
    <div className='p-4'>
      <BackButton />
      <h1 className='text-3xl my-4'>Delete Book</h1>
      {loading ? <Spinner /> : ''}
      <div className='flex flex-col items-center border-2 border-sky-400 rounded-xl w-[600px] p-8 mx-auto'>
        <h3 className='text-2xl'>Are You Sure You want to delete this book?</h3>

        <button
          className='p-4 bg-red-600 text-white m-8 w-full'
          onClick={handleDeleteBook}
        >
          Yes, Delete it
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DeleteBook;
```

**Any help, tips, or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!**

- Checked my frontend code to ensure that the "id" value is correctly passed to the DELETE request.
- Verified the URL structure to ensure that the "id" value is appropriately included in the request URL.
- Reviewed my backend code, particularly the DELETE route, to confirm that it handles the "id" parameter correctly.

Comment: When you issue a `Model.findById(id)`  or `Model.findByIdAndDelete(id)` mongoose will cast the value of `id` to an ObjectId for you. It seems that the `request.params.id` is not set. In your `handleDeleteBook` function can you confirm if `console.log('id=', id)` actually logs the value before you send the `axios.delete`?

Comment: It says: "id= undefined"

Comment: That means your `const { id } = useParams();` isn't doing what you expect it to do.

Comment: yes, that what I'm trying to figure out. any ideas?

Comment: The useParams hook returns an object of key/value pairs of the dynamic params from the current URL that were matched by the <Route path>. Child routes inherit all params from their parent routes. See [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params). Have you implemented this?

Comment: `const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='/books/create' element={<CreateBook />} />
      <Route path='/books/details/:id' element={<ShowBook />} />
      <Route path='/books/edit/:id' element={<EditBook />} />
      <Route path='/books/delete/:id' element={<DeleteBook />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};`

Comment: As far as I'm aware from my brief time using React, when you issue the `axios.delete` the url on the page needs to be `/books/delete/1234` because you have `<Route path='/books/delete/:id'` so `useParams` will put `1234` in the `id` variable.